# Angular Material table not showing data from API call

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am stuck trying to figure out why my mat-table is not showing my data...
I am using Angular 15 and angular material 15

**Here is my HTML component code:**

```
          <mat-divider></mat-divider>
          <table mat-table [dataSource]="terjatveTable" class="mat-elevation-z8">
            <!-- Name Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.series.name }}</td>
            </ng-container>

            <!-- Series Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="series">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Value</th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.series.value }}</td>
            </ng-container>

            <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumnsTableOne"></tr>
            <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumnsTableOne;"></tr>
          </table>
```

**here is the componenent.ts file code:**

```
 displayedColumnsTableOne: string[] = ['name', 'series'];
 terjatveTable: terjatveTableData[];

  getSingleCustomerTerjatveChartData() {
    const id = Number(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));
    this.customerService.getSingleCustomerTerjatveChartData(id).subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        if(data.error) {
          this.errorMessage = true;
        } else {
          this.terjatveTable = data;
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log('Error', error);
        this.terjatveTable = null;
        this.errorMessage = error.error === 'No data';
      });
  }
```

and here is the example of data I get from api call:

```
[
    {
        "name": "51399",
        "series": [
            {
                "name": "0-30 dni",
                "value": 12026.899999999999636202119290828704833984375
            },
            {
                "name": "30-60 dni",
                "value": 1293.259999999999990905052982270717620849609375
            },
            {
                "name": "60-90 dni",
                "value": 0
            },
            {
                "name": "90-180 dni",
                "value": 629.98000000000001818989403545856475830078125
            },
            {
                "name": "180+ dni",
                "value": 129.729999999999989768184605054557323455810546875
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: `this.terjatveTable = data.series[0]` and use `element.name`, `element.value`

Comment: @Eliseo this return this error: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'n.series[0]')

Comment: sorry: `data[0].series`. You get an array with an unique element. this element has a property "series" that is the array you want to show.

Comment: @Eliseo your comment is the correct anwser to my question

Answer (score 1):

You need to input an array to datasource to render. So please refer the below code.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';

@Component({
  selector: 'table-basic-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-basic-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-basic-example.html',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [MatTableModule],
})
export class TableBasicExample {
  links: Array<string>;
  displayedColumnsTableOne: string[] = ['name', 'series'];
  terjatveTable: any[];

  ngOnInit() {
    const data = [
      {
        name: '51399',
        series: [
          {
            name: '0-30 dni',
            value: 12026.899999999999636202119290828704833984375,
          },
          {
            name: '30-60 dni',
            value: 1293.259999999999990905052982270717620849609375,
          },
          {
            name: '60-90 dni',
            value: 0,
          },
          {
            name: '90-180 dni',
            value: 629.98000000000001818989403545856475830078125,
          },
          {
            name: '180+ dni',
            value: 129.729999999999989768184605054557323455810546875,
          },
        ],
      },
    ];
    this.terjatveTable = data;
  }
}
```

html

```
<table
  mat-table
  [dataSource]="terjatveTable[0].series"
  class="mat-elevation-z8"
>
  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.name }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Series Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="series">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Value</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.value }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumnsTableOne"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumnsTableOne"></tr>
</table>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/waahqd-eadlf6)

Comment: @weinde does this answer fix your issue?

Answer (score 1):

You want to display the `name` and `value` from the `series`, but the `series` is an array and you can't access the nested property in your current way.

In case that there could be multiple elements in the root array, you should **flatten** the nested array in this form:

```
[
    {
      name: '51399',
      series: {
        name: '0-30 dni',
        value: 12026.899999999999636202119290828704833984375,
      }
    },
    ...
]
```

```
terjatveTable!: any[];

this.terjatveTable = data.reduce((acc: any[], cur: any) => {
    cur.series.forEach((x: any) => {
      acc.push({
        ...cur,
        series: x,
      });
    });

    return acc;
  }, [] as any[]);
```

In my example, I use the `any[]` type instead of `terjatveTableData[]` as unsure your `terjatveTableData` structure.

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-nznabk?file=src%2Fmain.ts)